# Woocommerce REST API no response with BASIC auth and SSL installed

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, ssl, woocommerce

API response from POSTMAN: http://prntscr.com/lut035

Got the data when SSL certificate off from settings.

Error log when I try to get data from Android application.

W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:333)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:167)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:209)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:353)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:342)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:260)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:450)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:401)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:514)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.mcc.eshopper.network.http.BaseHttp.getResponseInString(BaseHttp.java:169)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.mcc.eshopper.network.http.BaseHttp.sendRequest(BaseHttp.java:157)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.mcc.eshopper.network.http.BaseHttp.doInBackground(BaseHttp.java:73)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.mcc.eshopper.network.http.BaseHttp.doInBackground(BaseHttp.java:30)
12-14 14:25:33.504 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:571)
12-14 14:25:33.505 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
12-14 14:25:33.506 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:329)
12-14 14:25:33.506 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:  ... 22 more
12-14 14:25:33.506 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
12-14 14:25:33.506 25597-25622/com.app16koti W/System.err:  ... 28 more

Comment: Got the solution. It was due to SSL certificate. The certificate we've used unknown to Android ecosystem so need to integrate inside app. here is the code.

Comment: source link: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java

Comment: // loading CAs from an InputStream
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream cert = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.www_16koti_com);
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
            } finally { cert.close(); }

Comment: // creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
  // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

Comment: // creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            //////////////////////









            //URL url = new URL(requestUrl);

            HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());